# Help interpreting the output from a mediation analysis

Tags: spss, interpretation, mediation, interaction

Currently I'm working on some organisational research. Just to get a bit of a idea of what I'm research; I'm looking at impact of leadership on how enthusiastically work. I believe the relationship of the leader, and follower impact are important, as is the ambition of a worker.

So I'm looking at:

1. Leadership = TFL_MEAN = X
2. Enthusiasm = ENGAG_ME = Y
3. Relationship = LMX_MEAN = M
4. Ambition = Growth_N

I examined the impact of TFL (X) on ENGAG_ME (Y), where I take LMX_ME (M) as a mediator, and Growth Need  (W) as moderator of the relationship between X, and M. This gives the following model:

[image]

I used the PROCESS macro, using model 8, to instantly test the model (the output is below). I'm wondering whether I'm interpreting the output right.

I Interpret it as that:

1. Growth_N is moderating the relationship between TFL_MEAN, and ENGAG_ME (due to the significant interaction, b =0.449, p=.028)
2. Significant direct effect of SL_MEAN on LMX_MEAN (b=.665, p <.001), but not on ENGAG_ME (b=.322, p = .109)
3. Growth_N is not moderating the relationship between SL_MEAN, and LMX_MEAN, due to the insignicant interaction (b=.098, p =.276)

So far, so good (I think). Next up are the "Conditional direct effect(s) of X on Y at values of the moderator(s)". I interpret this as (now I really don't know if this is right):

1. for low Growth_N (defined as minus 1 SD) there is an impact on ENGAG_ME, so when one has low levels the positive association between SL_MEAN, and ENGAG_ME strengthens.

And for the "Conditional indirect effect(s) of X on Y at values of the moderator(s):", I interpret this as (I don't really know whether this is right either):

1. The moderated mediation, and they are all significant, and their effect increases as their values increase. Thus the impact of SL_MEAN on ENGAG_ME, increases, as LMX_MEAN, and Growth_N increas.

After this the line "Indirect effect of highest order product:" pops up, showing LMX as insignificant. Does anyone know what this means?

```
************************************************************************** 
Model = 8 
    Y = ENGAG_ME 
    X = SL_MEAN 
    M = LMX_MEAN 
    W = Growth_N 
LMX MEAN 
Sample size 
        122 

************************************************************************** 
Outcome: LMX_MEAN 

Model Summary 
         R      R-sq       MSE         F       df1       df2         p 
      ,693      ,481      ,133    36,442     3,000   118,000      ,000 

Model 
             coeff        se         t         p      LLCI      ULCI 
constant     3,904      ,033   118,077      ,000     3,839     3,970 
SL_MEAN       ,664      ,064    10,402      ,000      ,538      ,791 
Growth_N      ,016      ,047      ,342      ,733     -,078      ,110 
int_1         ,098      ,089     1,094      ,276     -,079      ,275 

Product terms key: 

 int_1    SL_MEAN     X     Growth_N 

************************************************************************** 
Outcome: ENGAG_ME 

Model Summary 
         R      R-sq       MSE         F       df1       df2         p 
      ,558      ,311      ,675    13,209     4,000   117,000      ,000 

Model 
             coeff        se         t         p      LLCI      ULCI 
constant     2,270      ,812     2,794      ,006      ,661     3,879 
LMX_MEAN      ,629      ,207     3,034      ,003      ,218     1,039 
SL_MEAN       ,322      ,199     1,617      ,109     -,072      ,716 
Growth_N      ,348      ,107     3,258      ,001      ,137      ,560 
int_2        -,449      ,202    -2,220      ,028     -,850     -,048 

Product terms key: 

 int_2    SL_MEAN     X     Growth_N 

******************** DIRECT AND INDIRECT EFFECTS ************************* 

Conditional direct effect(s) of X on Y at values of the moderator(s): 
  Growth_N    Effect        SE         t         p      LLCI      ULCI 
     -,702      ,637      ,235     2,709      ,008      ,171     1,103 
      ,000      ,322      ,199     1,617      ,109     -,072      ,716 
      ,702      ,007      ,254      ,026      ,979     -,496      ,509 

Conditional indirect effect(s) of X on Y at values of the moderator(s): 

Mediator 
          Growth_N    Effect   Boot SE  BootLLCI  BootULCI 
LMX_MEAN     -,702      ,374      ,133      ,169      ,715 
LMX_MEAN      ,000      ,418      ,132      ,208      ,733 
LMX_MEAN      ,702      ,461      ,148      ,221      ,797 

Values for quantitative moderators are the mean and plus/minus one SD from mean. 
Values for dichotomous moderators are the two values of the moderator. 

----- 
Indirect effect of highest order product: 

Mediator 
            Effect  SE(Boot)  BootLLCI  BootULCI 
LMX_MEAN      ,062      ,070     -,051      ,232 

******************** INDEX OF MODERATED MEDIATION ************************ 

Mediator 
             Index  SE(Boot)  BootLLCI  BootULCI 
LMX_MEAN      ,062      ,070     -,051      ,232 

******************** ANALYSIS NOTES AND WARNINGS ************************* 

Number of bootstrap samples for bias corrected bootstrap confidence intervals: 
     1000 

Level of confidence for all confidence intervals in output: 
    95,00 

NOTE: The following variables were mean centered prior to analysis: 
 SL_MEAN  Growth_N 

------ END MATRIX -----
```

Comment: what is TFL LMX Sl etc.